# Can't "flutter run --release" after upgrading to iOS 17

Tags: flutter, xcode

I just upgraded to Xcode 15.0 and iOS 17, and then I encountered this problem. How to solve it?

```
Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory with suffix 'DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'. This probably means you don't have Xcode installed, you will need to launch the app manually and logging output will not be shown!
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008110-0018494802D0401E.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
```

Comment: before archiving it, Did you call a function pod update repo? First, Then try to archive but make sure to select RUNNER>ANY IOS Device

Answer (score 0):

temporary workaround for IOS.17 , please note the following steps will make the app building and running on IOS.17, XCode.15.

1. add the following to pdfile:

post_install do |installer|

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

```
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) 

target.build_configurations.each do |config| 

  xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path 

  xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path) 

  xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR") 

  File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod } 

  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0' 

end
```

end

end

2. add the following to pubspec.yaml:

   dependency_overrides:

   flutter_inappwebview:

   ```
   git: 

     url: https://github.com/vixez/flutter_inappwebview.git 

     ref: fix-xcode-17
   ```
3. update the following in Xcode

- Open IOS folder in XCODE
- select Runnner
- go to Build Settings
- search for "User Script Sandboxing"
- change its value from "yes" to "NO"

a. Open IOS folder in XCODE

```
b. select Runnner 

c. go to Build Settings 

d. search for "User Script Sandboxing" 

e. change its value from "yes" to "NO"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and fixed it by upgrading iOS version on my iPhone.